# Best way to read contents of file into a set in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I'm learning Clojure and as an exercise I wanted to write something like the unix "comm" command.

To do this, I read the contents of each file into a set, then use difference/intersection to show exclusive/common files.

After a lot of repl-time I came up with something like this for the set creation part:

```
(def contents (ref #{}))
(doseq [line (read-lines "/tmp/a.txt")]
  (dosync (ref-set contents (conj @contents line))))
```

(I'm using duck-streams/read-lines to seq the contents of the file).

This is my first stab at any kind of functional programming or lisp/Clojure. For instance, I couldn't understand why, when I did a conj on the set, the set was still empty. This lead me to learning about refs.

1. Is there a better Clojure/functional way to do this? By using ref-set, am I just twisting the code to a non-functional mindset or is my code along the lines of how it should be done?
2. Is there a a library that already does this? This seems like a relatively ordinary thing to want to do but I couldn't find anything like it.

Comment: Brian Carper's answer is good. Avoid using duck-streams. It's deprecated, with most of its functionality folded in to `clojure.core` and `clojure.java.io`.

Comment: About your comment that the set "was still empty"; it sounds like you are expecting mutable behavior. Remember that in clojure the data types are immutable. Building up collections is done recursively, hence the use of `reduce` as shown by Brian Carper (`into` uses `reduce` internally).

Comment: @DaveRay I wasn't aware of the status of duck-streams. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @AlexStoddard Yes, that was exactly my mistake. It's one thing to read about immutability, another thing altogether to really understand it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Clojure 1.3:

```
user> (require '[clojure.java [io :as io]])
nil
user> (line-seq (io/reader "foo.txt"))
("foo" "bar" "baz")
user> (into #{} (line-seq (io/reader "foo.txt")))
#{"foo" "bar" "baz"}
```

`line-seq` gives you a lazy sequence where each item in the sequence is a line in the file.

`into` dumps it all into a set.  To do what you were trying to do (add each item one by one into a set), rather than `doseq` and refs, you could do:

```
user> (reduce conj #{} (line-seq (io/reader "foo.txt")))
#{"foo" "bar" "baz"}
```

Note that the Unix `comm` compares two sorted files, which is likely a more efficient way to compare files than doing set intersection.

Edit: Dave Ray is right, to avoid leaking open file handles it's better to do this:

```
user> (with-open [f (io/reader "foo.txt")]
        (into #{} (line-seq f)))
#{"foo" "bar" "baz"}
```

Comment: @BrianCarper Thanks, this is really helpful. The use of line-seq seems more natural. I had only seen reduce being used to sum up values in a sequence, or something similar so it's interesting to see it used to create another collection.

Comment: You can use the function `set` instead of `(into #{} ...`

Answer (score 0):

I always read with `slurp` and after that split with `re-seq` due to my needs.